# Duvida ao Preencher um combo-box com Selenium e Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, combobox

Estou tentando automatizar uma rotina porem não estou conseguindo avançar em uma parte que tenho que selecionar um combobox de uma pagina com selenium.

O campo que quero preencher é o seguinte, 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em todos os campos até chegar aqui, consegui navegar com "find_element_by_id", porem nesse caso não funciona.

Ultima tentativa que fiz foi com "find_element_by_xpath" porem sem sucesso.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Chrome_exe = r'C:\Projetos\Integração\chromedriver.exe'

user = "xxxxxxx"
pwd = "xxxxxxx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Chrome_exe)
driver.get("https://xxxxxxxxx/#/login?to=~2Ffollow_up~2Factual_budget")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
elem.send_keys(user)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/fildset/div/div/div/select").click();
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro,

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/fildset/div/div/div/select").click();
>
> c:\program
>   files\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
>   in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
>       392             element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkKe6.png)')
>       393         """
>   --> 394         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
>       395 
>       396     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):
>
> c:\program
>   files\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
>   in find_element(self, by, value)
>       976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
>       977             'using': by,
>   --> 978             'value': value})['value']
>       979 
>       980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
>
> c:\program
>   files\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
>   in execute(self, driver_command, params)
>       319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
>       320         if response:
>   --> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>       322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
>       323                 response.get('value', None))
>
> c:\program
>   files\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py
>   in check_response(self, response)
>       240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
>       241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
>   --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       243 
>       244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
>
> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div/div/div/fildset/div/div/div/select"}
>   (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)

Alguém consegue me ajudar?
Grato!

Answer (score -1):

Pedro para utilizar o xpath você precisa informar a posição em que ele se encontra na pagina por exemplo aqui:

```
 elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/fildset/div/div/div/select").click();
```

ficaria algo assim:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/fildset/div/div/div/select[1]").click();`
```

Você pode buscar mais apoio aqui caso necessário: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Felipe, desculpe pela pergunta idiota, mas nao tenho muita experiencia com web. Tem alguma forma de eu pegar esse caminho de alguma forma mais acertiva no Chrome?

Comment: Pedro também não sou expert nessa área e sempre usei o xpath como ultimo dos recursos então não posso te dizer se existe uma maneira melhor. Pedi para você verificar o caminho pois é muito comum utilizando o xpath o erro estar justamente ai.

Comment: Oi, no selenium pode fazer alguma ação nos componentes via ID
ou nome da classe ou xpath. essa app que vc esta automatizando usa Angular-JS
pode tentar acessar via css, tente encontrar explicações no pagina oficial selenium,
o basico é driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model="tableName"]")).
O uso do xpath pode dar problema futuramente qualquer mudança no cod pode 
não encontrar o  IU.